# How can I get my drill back?

Tags: terraria

My friend stole my drill in Terraria and he won't give it back. I’m wondering if there is anyway for me to get it back?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about interpersonal relations are not in this site's purview.

Comment: This was closed without mentioning that you can, in theory, craft a new cacti pickaxe and then continue from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your only options are to

1. Craft a new Drill
2. Steal it back
3. Make him give it back (He would if he's really your friend)

A Drill / Pickaxe is 100% necessary for progression in the game so if you can't do any of those for some odd reason you're out of luck.